# Указанная родительский каталог не является каталогом

Tags: modx, файловая-система

Я создал новый источник файлов, назначил права доступа к этому источнику группе пользователей manager. Затем я создаю каталог в этом источнике, а в этом созданном каталоге я хочу создать ещё каталог (вложенный), но при попытке создания появляется окно с ошибкой:

> Указанная родительский каталог не является каталогом

Также не загружаются файлы в каталог, созданный непосредственно в корне источника файлов. В ист. файлов "filesystem" всё нормально. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Права доступа у пользователя к каталогу есть? Проверьте.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.